# How can I keep track of how many times a sprite has been touched in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

In my program, I have sprites fall from the top of the screen and the user taps each sprite to keep them from falling to the ground, which results in game over. These sprites are in the shape of stars.

**My question is, how can I keep track of how many times each star has been tapped, so when a user taps the star 3 times, it disappears?**

I currently have 2 different types of stars fall from the sky, and whenever they are added to the game, they are added into an array. Hopefully my code explains what I'm doing.

I'm new to objective C, so please feel free to let me know what else is wrong in my code... looking to get better!

```
#import "MainScene.h"
#import <CoreGraphics/CGGeometry.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#import "Star.h"
#import "redStar.h"

@implementation MainScene {
    CCSprite *_star;
    CCSprite *_redStar;
    CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
    CCNode *_ground;
    CCNode *_leftWall;
    CCNode *_rightWall;
    CCNode *_ceiling;
    CCLabelTTF *_scoreLabel;
    NSInteger _points;
    BOOL _gameOver;
    CCButton *_restartButton;
    NSInteger _taps;
    NSMutableArray *_allStars;
    NSInteger _rando;
}

- (void)didLoadFromCCB {
    _rando = (arc4random_uniform(1000));
    self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
    self.starList = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self addNewStar];

    // set collision txpe
    _ground.physicsBody.collisionType = @"level";
    // set this class as delegate
    _physicsNode.collisionDelegate = self;
}

-(void)addNewStar {
    float ranNum01 = (arc4random_uniform(200)+60);
    float pos1 = ranNum01;

    _star = (Star *)[CCBReader load:@"Star"];
    _star.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"starGroup";
    _star.physicsBody.collisionType = @"star";
    _star.position = ccp(pos1,500);

    [_physicsNode addChild:_star];
    [self.starList addObject:_star];
}

-(void)addRedStar {
    float ranNum01 = (arc4random_uniform(200)+60);
    float pos1 = ranNum01;
    _redStar = (redStar *)[CCBReader load:@"redStar"];
    _redStar.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"starGroup";
    _redStar.physicsBody.collisionType = @"star";
    _redStar.position = ccp(pos1,500);
    [_physicsNode addChild:_redStar];
    [self.starList addObject:_redStar];
}

-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair star:(CCNode *)star level:(CCNode *)level {
    [self gameOver];
    return TRUE;
}

- (void)update:(CCTime)delta {
    // clamp velocity.  -1*MAXFLOAT means no falling speed limit.
    float yVelocity = clampf(_star.physicsBody.velocity.y, -1 * MAXFLOAT, 1000.f);
    _star.physicsBody.velocity = ccp(0, yVelocity);
}

- (void)starDropper
{
    if (_taps == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if ((_taps + (_rando)) % 5 == 0)
    {
        [self addNewStar];
    }

    if ((_taps + (_rando)) % 8 == 0)
    {
        [self addRedStar];
    }
}

- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    float ranNum1 = (arc4random_uniform(100));
    float ranNum2 = (arc4random_uniform(100));
    float sideForce = ranNum1 - ranNum2;

    self._tappedStar = NO;

    if (!_gameOver) {
        for (_star in self.starList) {

            CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:_physicsNode];
            if(CGRectContainsPoint([_star boundingBox], touchLocation)) {

                [_star.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(sideForce, 2500.f)];
                [_star.physicsBody applyAngularImpulse:2500.f];
                self._tappedStar = YES;
                _taps++;
                _points++;
                _scoreLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _points];
            }
        }

        if (self._tappedStar == NO)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (self._tappedStar == YES)
        {
            [self starDropper];
        }
    }
}

- (void)restart {
    CCScene *scene = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"MainScene"];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
}

- (void)gameOver {
    if (!_gameOver) {

        _gameOver = TRUE;
        _restartButton.visible = TRUE;
        _star.rotation = 90.f;
        _star.physicsBody.allowsRotation = FALSE;
        [_star stopAllActions];

        CCActionMoveBy *moveBy = [CCActionMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.2f position:ccp(-2, 2)];
        CCActionInterval *reverseMovement = [moveBy reverse];
        CCActionSequence *shakeSequence = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[moveBy,     reverseMovement]];
        CCActionEaseBounce *bounce = [CCActionEaseBounce actionWithAction:shakeSequence];
        [self runAction:bounce];
    }
}

@end
```

**UPDATE: I think I'm close..this is what I've got, but I must be missing something because the stars still won't disappear...ALSO - "world" is an undeclared identifier - not sure how to identify**

```
@implementation MainScene {

CCSprite *touchedStar;
CCSprite *_star;
CCSprite *_redStar;

CCSprite *oneTappedStar;
CCSprite *twoTappedStar;
CCSprite *threeTappedStar;

CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;

CCLabelTTF *_scoreLabel;
NSInteger _points;

BOOL _gameOver;

CCButton *_restartButton;
NSInteger _rando;

CCActionFadeIn *fadeIn;

}

- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

float ranNum1 = (arc4random_uniform(100));
float ranNum2 = (arc4random_uniform(100));
float sideForce = ranNum1 - ranNum2;

self._tappedStar = NO;


if (!_gameOver) {

    for (_star in self.starList) {


    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:_physicsNode];
        if(CGRectContainsPoint([_star boundingBox], touchLocation))

        {
            [_star.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(sideForce, 2500.f)];
            [_star.physicsBody applyAngularImpulse:2500.f];
            self._tappedStar = YES;
            _taps++;
            _points++;
            _scoreLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _points];

           // starTaps++;


            if (touchedStar == threeTappedStar) {

                [self removeChild:touchedStar];
                world->DestroyBody(touchedStar.physicsBody);

            }

            //3

            if (touchedStar == twoTappedStar) {

                touchedStar = threeTappedStar;
            }

            //2

            if (touchedStar == oneTappedStar) {

                touchedStar = twoTappedStar;
            }

            //1

            if (touchedStar == _star) {

                touchedStar = oneTappedStar;
            }




        }
    }



    if (self._tappedStar == NO)
    {
        return;

    }


    if (self._tappedStar == YES)
    {
        [self starDropper];

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

float ranNum1 = (arc4random_uniform(100));
float ranNum2 = (arc4random_uniform(100));
float sideForce = ranNum1 - ranNum2;
CCSprite *starTouched;

if (!_gameOver) {
    for (starTouched in starList) {

        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:_physicsNode];
        if(CGRectContainsPoint([starTouched boundingBox], touchLocation)) {

            [starTouched.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(sideForce, 2500.f)];
            [starTouched.physicsBody applyAngularImpulse:2500.f];
            _taps++;
            _points++;
            _scoreLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)_points];


            if (starTouched.scale == 1.000002) {

                [_physicsNode removeChild:starTouched];

                CCLOG(@"DESTROY");
            }

            if (starTouched.scale == 1.000001) {

                starTouched.scale = 1.000002;
                CCLOG(@"2");
            }

            // FOR DIFFERENT TYPE OF STARS

            //star
            if (starTouched == _star) {

                starTouched.scale = 1.000001;
                CCLOG(@"1");
            }

            //redStar
            if (starTouched == _redStar) {

                starTouched.scale = 1.000001;
                CCLOG(@"1");
            }
         }

    }

   }
}
```

Comment: Referring to your second code, where would you put this code?

Comment: touchBegan method, where you get what star was touched.

Comment: Ok, one more question then, how/where do I define touchedStar and oneTappedStar (etc.)?  Thanks so much for your help!  I think this will work.

Comment: In your implementation: CCSprite *oneTappedStar (etc). touchedStar is your _star in touchBegan method.

Comment: hey @flowmachine1, i just updated my code to reflect what you did, but my stars still aren't disappearing.  I think I'm really close, can you see what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks so much for all this help.

Comment: check out my edit, man. it should work for you. replace your touchBegan method. maybe little messy, but it's work. If you need more help in future I need to know what you are doing with stars.

Comment: oh, my code don't track option where star1 tapped two times and star2 tapped 3 times and destroyed, after that you can't destroy star1 :( but it's a good starting point for you.

Comment: Yea, i ran into that problem.  I am trying to figure it out.  I feel like I need to add the yellow stars in an array and the red stars in a separate array..but I'm not sure if that would work either and if so, not sure how to track and save the taps on each individual star.   If you have any ideas, feel free to shoot them at me!!